# Saving Sequelize Query Text In Database

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query that I would like to *save in a database and then execute on demand*. In order to do this I am first testing how this would work in a variable as a string (because in a database it will be stored as a string):

```
queryToRun = models.user.findAll({
  attributes: [
    ['name', 'name'],
    [Sequelize.literal("COUNT(DISTINCT(user.id))"), "user_count"]
  ],
  group: Sequelize.col("user.name")
})
```

With this query I would like to use it like so:

```
Promise.all(queryToRun);
```

I am successfully able to save the object (object that goes inside `findAll` with the attributes etc) as a string and then execute, but I can't figure out how to save every part of the query. I want to save the actual `"model.user.findAll()"`string and evaluate it at a later time.

This is important because I want to define the model that I need to run `findAll` on and save it in the database.

Comment: What about creating a view instead of storing it as a string?

Comment: Not a bad work around, but I need it to be created and stored dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple

1. Don't use the multiline string it trips up the function call for some reason
2. Use eval to evaluate the string

Example:

```
let queryToRun = 'models.project.findAll({})';
Promise.all([eval(queryToRun)]);
```